# Can bootstrap-vue table row selection be selected via a checkbox

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I currently have a bootstrap vue table that has the left column all being checkboxes. I have set the table rows to be selectable which is working fine. I'd like to be able to select the rows via a checkbox and not clicking on the actual .

I'd also like to know if it's possible to select all rows via the top left checkbox.

take a look at my jsfiddle to see what i have now.

- rows selectable via checkbox for each row
- all rows selectable via top left checkbox

https://jsfiddle.net/itsjess/mLztuf6o/2/

```
<b-table id="my-table" class="mb-20" :borderless="true" 
      :items="merchants" :fields="fields" selectable @row- 
      selected="rowSelected" selectedVariant="success" :per- 
      page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" small responsive>
     <template slot="HEAD_index" slot-scope="data">
                <b-form-checkbox></b-form-checkbox>
            </template>

     <template slot="index" slot-scope="data">
                <b-form-checkbox :id="'checkbox' + data.index" v-model="data.item.index" checked="checked">
                </b-form-checkbox>
            </template>

    <template slot="outlet" slot-scope="data">
                {{ data.item.name }}
            </template>

     <template slot="orderacc" slot-scope="data">
                on
            </template>

     <template slot="taskcomp" slot-scope="data">
                40%
            </template>
</b-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any support for selecting rows via checkbox in bootstrap table, so probably you have to handle this case by yourself:

Remove `selectable` and `@row-selected` bindings and add selected items to your own array.
I prepared some implementation from your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/unp7jzwo/

P.S. If you will have table with dynamic items which you will receive through some API it will be necessary to store `uuid` as checkbox value instead of an object reference (like in my jsfiddle).

Comment: Would it be possible to implement it as a mixin ? So that each view that needs such a table element could benefit of it easily, without having to reimplement it again (and keeping DRY principles)

Answer (score 4):

i achieved this using Refs on the table and scoped cell slot.
i added a cell scoped slot then used rowSelected which is aboolean to my checkbox v-model then added a change event to also trigger selection of the row when a checkbox is checked and unchecked.

```
 <b-table ref="tableRef" selectable   select-mode="multi">
 </b-table>

   <template #cell(selected)="data">
          <b-form-checkbox
            @change="checked(data.index, data.rowSelected)"
            v-model="data.rowSelected"
          >
          </b-form-checkbox>          
    </template>

 checked(index: number, checked: boolean) {
    let tableRef: any = this.$refs.tableRef
    // to select all use tableRef.selectAllRows()
    // to see all availabe table properties just do a console.log(tableRef)
    if (checked === false){
    tableRef.selectRow(index)
    } else {
      tableRef.unselectRow(index)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I just had to change checked === true and it worked perfectly, thanks.